# arrayList/vector add element at position , method

Tags: java, addition

I am trying to do something like:

```
 ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList(15);
 al.add(5, "test");
```

my case with vector but it doesnt matter. I am missing something trivial.

However I get index out of bound exception.

Method api description:

"Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices). " - so?

My situation is that I get UDP packets and try to place their data them into structure according to header sequence number.

Update: same happens with .set

Comment: Can you explain the behavior you are experiencing? It is difficult to understand your question. " my case with vector but it doesnt matter. I am missing something trivial."

Comment: Because vector .add and .set methods have same behavior as for arrayList. I got expected answer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For beginners the constructor of ArrayList is confusing. 
Putting

```
 new ArrayList(15);
```

is basically just an optimization of your program upfront. The class **ArrayList** is basically just a wrapper around a native Java array. In this example the actual internal array will be created with 15 elements. When you put more than that, the **ArrayList** class just creates a bigger array and copies over the contents from the original array. Putting an initial capacity does not make sense very often. I only use it when I know from the beginning that I will story a huge number of elements in the ArrayList (say one million).

I know, this behavior is very confusing, especially if you are coming from a language like PHP, where you can just do:

```
al[] = Array();
al[15] = "I am a fifteen year old UDP package";
```

Basically the `add(index, element)` method just works if you have an ArrayList that contains more than *index* elements, squeezing the new element in after *index-1*.

For the solution:

If you know that you will be receiving 15 elements max, it is perfectly ok to use an ordinary **array** like so:

```
String[] al = new String[15];
al[5] = "Tralala";
```

If you don't know the number of elements I would store them in a **List** and sort that list after all packages have been received.

Comment: As stated in the answer by @mark-byers an ArrayList still has to be contiguous.

Comment: thanks, well unfortunately he deleted his answer being upset about my response, though I suggested to move that from comment to answer. Anyway, I see the point.

Comment: Oh well, yes it disappeared. Still a *SortedList* as suggested by @mark-byers would also be the way I would go, when I didn't know how many elements there would be. Also: downvoting on helpful answers is no good... :)

Answer (score 3):

The constructor accepts the **capacity**, not the **size**. You can only add elements at indices less than or equal to the size of the ArrayList, which in this case is zero.

Here is a workaround to create an ArrayList with 15 elements:

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[15]));
```

Comment: @allesblinkt: I know it's not elegant, but it's the only way I know to make an ArrayList of a certain size without a loop (which isn't that elegant either).

Comment: I know you know. I was really tempted to answer something like this myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
int size = a.size();
if(5 < size){
    a.add(5,"Hello");
}else{
    System.out.println("Index not present as size is less");
}
```

Or while creating the Collection you can mention the size, as

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>(10);
```